# Can Spider read the info inside <div> or <span> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css, robots.txt

I have this line in my webpage

```
<span class="gwt-CheckBox" id="117722" title="the first generation of iPhone 
that was designed and marketed by Apple Inc" style="display: block;">
```

My question is that:
 can Spider read the line "**the first generation of iPhone that was designed and marketed by Apple Inc**"?

Comment: can Google spider read it? can Yahoo or Bing spider read it?

Comment: If in the file `robot.txt` you have allowed the robot, then it would even read the love letter that you've sent to your girlfriend. No matter inside a `div`, `span`, `table` or what ever other HTML5 new element you use.

Comment: i don't have any robot.txt, so by default, it will info inside <span>...?

Comment: However, I am not sure about the `title` element. But 6th sense makes me believe, YES! It will read, because for the images, `alt` attribute is read by the Search Engines to provide the image results...

Comment: so you mean if the spider can read <span> &  if user search "first generation of iPhone site:mydomain.com" then it will show my url right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, on the Search engine websites when you search for an image. The engine search for the `alt` attribute of the `img` element to provide the results. Using this, I am sure the search engine would get a chance to read this `title` attribute of the element.

But it depends on the Search engine whether it wants to save this data or to skip it.

So what I mean is when you're allowing a robot to scan your page (which in turn you are allowing; because you don't have any robot.txt file in your root folder). So robot would scan, but on the server the Company would skip or delete the data that was sent to it from a `title` attribute of the element. Because `title` is just written to help the user know what to write here and how to write here. Search Engine has nothing to do with that.

However, you **should** try out using meta tags, some thing like

```
<meta name="information" description="the first generation of iPhone
```

that was designed and marketed by Apple Inc" />

I think, Search engine would provide a search result for this. Because they do save this data.

Here is a link for https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/79812?hl=en (meta tags that Google Understands)

MDN link for the element: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta

Get to know the valid values for this and get the coding continue!

Comment: if the spider can read <span> & if user search "first generation of iPhone site:mydomain.com" then it will show my url right?

Comment: Nope! It totally depends on the Search engine. Spider would scan your page, but Title values are **never** or **sometimes** saved! Not always, so it is better to follow the convention of writing the data inside the meta tags.

Comment: ok, thax you, i got it

Answer (score 1):

WHY?... Are you asking because you dont want it to be read or because you do want it to be read.

The answer is that - It may read it as it scans the code, but it wont take much priority in SEO over your page title, h1 tags and paragraph text this will be insignificant.

--- The question is not so much can it read div or span but rather can it read the contents of title=""

You would be better off putting the text in a heading or paragraph somewhere in the page **(if you really want to be sure it can be found)**

Comment: so you mean if the spider can read <span> & if user search "first generation of iPhone site:mydomain.com" then it will show my url right?

Comment: I want it to be read.

Comment: I dont think so, i dont think the contents of title="" tags will show up in search. Although I do not know for sure.

You would be better off putting the text in a heading or paragraph somewhere in the page (if you really want to be sure it can be found)